# How to remove standards fonts named: Sans, Serif, Monospace

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

On Ubuntu 22.04 there a several fonts named in standard ways: Sans, Serif, Monospace. Here an example from Google Chrome

[image]

I want completely remove this names from a system, how i do that? There no names for that in font manager

Answer (score 1):

Those are font categories and can't be removed.